# Galois group of $x^p-2px+p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $p\ge 5$ prime

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I proved that $x^5-2x+p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}$ so in $\mathbb{Q}$ by Gauss Lemma

I need (and I still can't) to prove that $x^5-2x+p$ has exactly three real roots and conclude that the Galois group is $S_5$.

**Edit:** I send a mail to teacher and he says that the problem was wrong: I need to prove that $x^5-2px+p$ has galois group $S_5$ instead of $x^5-2x+p$.

Comment: Have you tried using calculus? Find maxima/minima, and draw the graph?

Comment: $x^5-2x+1013$ has only one real root.

Comment: @GastónBurrull $x^5-2x+p$ has only one real root for any $p\geq 2$. Perhaps you mean $x^5-2x-p$ ?

Comment: Usually the polynomial is $X^p-2pX+p$ for $p\ge 5$ prime, with Galois group $S_p$.